# The meaning of "get the blood flowing"

Tags: meaning

"We gotta get the blood flowing with some friendly game!"

What does "get the blood flowing" mean here? Is it literally?

Comment: Work your heart rate up (either with exercise or something exciting).

Comment: It is an idiomatic way of saying "Let's get this party started!" though it does have a correct literal interpretation as well.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, it means 'flowing round the body', not 'bleeding'.